# Parsing multi-level javascript object and retrieve only keys

Tags: javascript

I need an array which will contain every key of my JavaScript object (e.g. ["CNS", "Atypical teratoid rhabdoid tumor", "Choroid plexus tumor", "Choroid plexus papilloma", [...])

Here's an excerpt of it :

```
    var tumor_types = {
    "CNS" : {
        "Atypical teratoid rhabdoid tumor" : {
            "Category" : "Direct referral",
            "Educational-page" : "/assets/educational-page/atypical-teratoid-rhabdoid-tumor.docx",
        },
        "Choroid plexus tumor" : {
            "Choroid plexus papilloma" : {
                "Category" : "Universal criteria",
                "Educational-page" : "/assets/educational-page/choroid-plexus-papilloma.docx",
            },
            "Choroid plexus carcinoma" : {
                "Category" : "Direct referral",
                "Educational-page" : "/assets/educational-page/choroid-plexus-carcinoma.docx",
            }
        },
        "Embryonal tumor of the CNS - NOS" : {
            "Category" : {
                "Algorithm" : 1,
                "Educational-page" : "/assets/educational-page/embryonal-tumor-CNS-NOS.docx"
            }
        },
        [...]
```

So, before the key "Category", I need the tumor name to be pushed into an array. This is my recursion function so far (my first time doing recursion):

```
    function get_all_tumors_name(data) {
    var result = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        result.push(key);

        console.log($.type(value));

        if(key != 'Category' && key != 'Educational-page') {
            var names = get_all_tumors_name(value);
            result = result.concat(names);
        }           

    });

    return result

}
```

When I ran my previous code, I had an array but inside of it I had a lot of "Category" and "Educational-page", which I do not want. That is why I added the  `key != 'Category' && key != 'Educational-page'` check. Could my condition be better? Or should I simply remove every "Category" and "Educational-page" from the array? That would seem to me not very optimal.

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: I will edit, hold on please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a recursive method that terminates a branch when an object with a `Category` key is found:

```js
var tumor_types={"CNS":{"Atypical teratoid rhabdoid tumor":{"Category":"Direct referral","Educational-page":"/assets/educational-page/atypical-teratoid-rhabdoid-tumor.docx",},"Choroid plexus tumor":{"Choroid plexus papilloma":{"Category":"Universal criteria","Educational-page":"/assets/educational-page/choroid-plexus-papilloma.docx",},"Choroid plexus carcinoma":{"Category":"Direct referral","Educational-page":"/assets/educational-page/choroid-plexus-carcinoma.docx",}},"Embryonal tumor of the CNS - NOS":{"Category":{"Algorithm":1,"Educational-page":"/assets/educational-page/embryonal-tumor-CNS-NOS.docx"}}}}

const getKeys = (obj, keys=[]) => {
  const theseKeys = Object.keys(obj);
  if (theseKeys.includes('Category')) return;
  keys.push(...theseKeys);
  const theseValues = Object.values(obj);
  theseValues.forEach(child => getKeys(child, keys));
  return keys;
}
console.log(getKeys(tumor_types));
```

Comment: Wow! That was quick

Comment: Awesome answer. There are some things in what you wrote I do not quite understand, but I will check around to see what it really does. Thank you so much, with your answer I will learn even more on javascript and my project will continue to advance fairly!